# Replace column values conditional on another column being equal to a vector

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(name=c('a','b','c', 'a'), value=c(1,1,1,1))

  digit value
1    1     1
2    2     1
3    3     1
4    1     1
```

and another list:

```
v <- c(1,3)
```

I want to change the values in value column to 0 if name matches the list v such that the output will be:

```
  digit value
1    1     0
2    2     1
3    3     0
4    1     0
```

Comment: `transform(df,value1 = value*(!name%in%name[v]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the logical vector with `%in%`, subset the 'value' and assign it to 0

```
df$value[df$digit %in% v] <- 0
df
#  name value
#1    1     0
#2    2     1
#3    3     0
#4    1     0
```

Or another option is

```
df$value <-  df$value *(!df$digit %in% v)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(value = replace(value, digit %in% v, 0))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[name %chin% v, value := 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[name %in% v, value := 0]
df

#   name value
#1:    a     0
#2:    b     1
#3:    c     0
#4:    a     0
```

Or using `replace` in base R

```
df$value <- replace(df$value, df$name %in% v, 0)
```